# Windows 10 guest VMs on Virtualbox 7.0 all rejecting correct password at login

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I have been running several Win10 VMs on VirtualBox 7.0 for 4-6 weeks without issue.  They were created on different dates.  The username and password were the same on all VMs.

Today, when attempting to login, each VM indicates the password has expired and must be reset.  When attempting to create a new password, the current password is rejected as "incorrect" by all VMs.  However, the password is *certainly* correct.

I have made no changes other than to increase the video memory of a single VM using the command below in the folder for the target VM:

`VBoxManage modifyvm <vm name> --vram 256`

Edit:

Fwiw, only some of the VMs were cloned.  So this behaviour is on more than one default installation from the ISO.

Comment: @John - You positive about that statement? I have never in 22 years of using NT based Windows installation, on my personal machine, been asked to change my password on a local account..

Comment: @John - [The default policy in a domain setting should s 42 days not 30 days.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/maximum-password-age) I can guarantee that it’s “not configured” on Professional and Home editions of Windows.

Comment: I deleted all my comments as my posts are normally always wrong. Bye